# Python Connect to Oracle DB

Tags: python, oracle, database-connection, connection-string, pyodbc

I currently use PYODBC to connect to MS SQL Server and MYSQL, but now need to access an Oracle database as well.

I have Oracle SQL Developer installed on my work comp (but there doesn't seem to be a separate Net Manager client per other SO posts), which I can use to access the DB.

Ideally, I would run what I need to in python, but am having difficulties.  As it stands, I have created a linked server object to the Oracle DB in a MS SQL Server DB as a work around, but this isn't ideal.

What do I need to do to get PYODBC (or substitute) to connect to Oracle?  Thanks very kindly.

Comment: PYODbC should work just as fine to connect to Oracle DBs - have you tried just making up a system ODBC connection to it and feeding it to Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue where I could connect to a database via Oracle SQL Developer but not via `pyodbc`. Someone else did most of the database setup, so I wasn't sure of the proper connection parameters. I'll run you through how I was able to connect on a Windows computer.

In the Start Menu I typed "odbc" and selected "Microsoft ODBC Administrator". Under the "System DSN" tab I found my DSN name (we'll call it myDSN) and corresponding driver (mine was "Oracle in OraClient11g_home2"). I also have to specify a username and password for my database so my connection line now looks like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{Oracle in OraClient11g_home2}', dsn='myDSN', uid='HODOR', pwd='hodor')
```

Maybe at this point it will work for you, but I still wasn't able to connect. This computer is a mess of 32 and 64 bit drivers so I figured I was pointing to the wrong one. So once again into the Start Menu, where under All Programs I found a folder called "Oracle in OraClient11g_home2" and right under it, one called "Oracle in OraClient11g_home32Bit". I changed my connection line in Python to the following:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{Oracle in OraClient11g_home32Bit}', dsn='myDSN', uid='HODOR', pwd='hodor')
```

And it connected.